# Can't run gradle tasks from Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, exec

I am trying to run some gradle tasks from java program, so I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method and it works as needed on windows but does not work on ubuntu. It must be the simple solution but I just can't get it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

        String[] cmd = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c","cd ~/temp/invokeG && gradle --info";
            };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        String lines = "";
        String resoults ="";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while((lines=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(lines);
        }
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + resoults);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" does it give an error? If so, please provide us with all the information given by the error. If it doesn't give the expected output, that also helps us help you.

Comment: it doesn't give any error, it just doesn't do what i want to be done.in windows i call getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd C:\Temp\invokeG && gradle assemble")and it works and i can see the response in Bufferedreader object
But when i try to call it from Ubuntu like getRuntime().exec({"/bin/bash","-c","cd ~/temp/invokeG && gradle dependencies"} it dosn't give any response

Comment: Are you sure the folder ~/temp/invokeG exists? Case sensitive of course. Please check the std out and std error in the `Process` object that `exec()` returns.

Comment: Yep, i am sure that the folder ~/temp/invokeG exists. because when i change to {"/bin/bash", "-c","cd ~/temp/invokeG && ls }" it works perfectly and show all the files in the directory.So as you said i add std error but it shows nothing.